# javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service

Tags: java, web-services, batch-file, cxf

I need desperate help to figure out the reason for the failure in creating the service.

My application is developed using Eclipse tool and it runs well there. It uses cxf-3.1.7 library collection. A console program that initializes the process to create the service to the API. Everything looks good and fine.

I am trying to deploy the code in another machine. I installed the necessary jre and other files. I created a batch file with all the necessary path and classpath settings. I need to run the batch file on a daily base, so that it pulls the data regularly. But, when I run the batch file, it fails to create the service with the above error message.

Can someone suggest me the reason if I am going wrong somewhere or any solution to get the service created. This is the batch file I have:

```
set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin 
set classpath=cxf-core-3.1.7.jar;cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.1.7.ja‌​r;sqljdbc42.jar;cxf-‌​rt-frontend-jaxws-3.‌​1.7.jar;wsdl4j-1.6.3‌​.jar;cxf-rt-wsdl-3.1‌​.7.jar;xmlschema-cor‌​e-2.2.1.jar;lib*.jar‌​;. 
java com.strongmail.services.v2.MailingService_MailingServicePort‌​_Client 
pause
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could we see your batch file?

Comment: This is the batch file I have.

set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin
set classpath=cxf-core-3.1.7.jar;cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.1.7.jar;sqljdbc42.jar;cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.7.jar;wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar;cxf-rt-wsdl-3.1.7.jar;xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar;lib\*.jar;.
java com.strongmail.services.v2.MailingService_MailingServicePort_Client
pause

Answer (score 4):

I've created java classes from wsdl with `org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava`. While creating an instance of the service, I had exact same exception at runtime:

> org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to
>   create service

Previous code:

```
URL wsdlURL = new URL("http://example.com/my_service.asmx");
MyWS mailWS = new MyWS(wsdlURL); // Exception is thrown here
```

Solution was weird. I've just added `?wsdl` next to service address:

```
URL wsdlURL = new URL("http://example.com/my_service.asmx?wsdl");
MyWS mailWS = new MyWS(wsdlURL);
```

Comment: Thanks. Faced same issue and this help me.

Comment: Even I have added ?WSDL next to my service still I am getting the above error ? Can you please let me in which scenario we can get the above error

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a client for a api has **SSL**, you should start the Java command with a necessary option.
-Dorg.apache.cxf.stax.allowInsecureParser=1